# Visifire candlestick doesn't autoscale

Tags: wpf, candlestick-chart, visifire

How can I make autoscale in Visifire Chart CandleStick ?

When I try it:

```
xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:Visifire.Charts;assembly=WPFVisifire.Charts"

<vc:Chart Width="500" Height="300" Theme="Theme2" Name="chartMain">
    <vc:Chart.Series>
        <vc:DataSeries RenderAs="CandleStick">
            <vc:DataSeries.DataPoints>
                <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="1" YValues="100.5,101.2,101.3,100.5"/>
                <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="2" YValues="100.8,100,101.1,101.4"/>
            </vc:DataSeries.DataPoints>
        </vc:DataSeries>
    </vc:Chart.Series>
</vc:Chart>
```

It doesn't aotuscale.

[image: example.jpg]

[project.rar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/le23l95atbr4pvt/VisifireCandlestickTrouble.rar?dl=0)

Comment: what you want to do ? your current chart doesn't show candlesticks.

Comment: if i add more vc:DataPoint it'll be candlestick. http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Chart_Types/candlestick_chart.htm

Comment: Now I've found min and max myself:

`<vc:Chart.AxesY>
                <vc:Axis AxisMaximum="{Binding Path=maxYAxces, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <vc:Axis AxisMinimum="{Binding Path=minYAxces, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </vc:Chart.AxesY>`

But on [this page](http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Reference/Attribute_Reference/AxisMaximum.htm) said that "The default value is automatically calculated from the DataPoints. Hence users need not set this value". And it don't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did following changes, and chart appears correctly. Your YValues are wrong. They should be according to Open, Close, High, Low. http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Reference/Attribute_Reference/YValues.htm

```
<Grid>
        <vc:Chart Theme="Theme2" Name="chartMain">
            <vc:Chart.AxesX>
                <vc:Axis AxisMaximum="20" />
            </vc:Chart.AxesX>

            <vc:Chart.AxesY>
                <vc:Axis AxisMinimum="95" />                
            </vc:Chart.AxesY>

            <vc:Chart.Series>
                <vc:DataSeries RenderAs="CandleStick">
                    <vc:DataSeries.DataPoints>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="1" YValues="100.5,101.2,101.3,100.5"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="2" YValues="100.8,100,101.4,99"/>
                    </vc:DataSeries.DataPoints>
                </vc:DataSeries>
            </vc:Chart.Series>
        </vc:Chart>
</Grid>
```

Comment: In YValues random values. I tried <vc:Chart.AxesX> but my data in DataPoint is dynamic and I don't know min and max value.

Comment: In your Model, you can find Min and Max values easily, and expose these with two properties which can be bound.

Comment: I do it now. But in [doc](http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Reference/Attribute_Reference/AxisMaximum.htm) said "The default value is automatically calculated from the DataPoints. Hence users need not set this value".